# How to import an Interface from a dependency of a dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript

Simple question, we have a custom package that uses `axios` as a dependency and exports a function that returns an Axios Client with some custom default configuration. The problem is that I want the `AxiosInstance` interface that is not exported from the package itself and `axios` it's not a dependency in my project.

```js
// @myCustomDep
import { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
export function createAxiosClient(): AxiosInstance  { //... }
```

```js
// Main project
import { createAxiosClient } from '@myCustomDep';

// Err: Cannot find name 'AxiosInstance'.
function buildClient(): AxiosInstance {
  const axiosClient = createAxiosClient();
  return axiosClient;
}
```

What would be the correct way of handling this import without modifying the underlying dependency (if possible)?

Comment: what kind of dependency is there betewwn `custom package` and `axios`? is it a `dependency`, `devDependency` or a `peerDependency`?

Comment: it is a dependency

Comment: Then it should be present in the `node_modules`. Go ahead anf put an `import { AxiosInstance } from "axios"` in your file where the compiler is complaining. Refer to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it is a dependency of your dependency, you may very well also list it as your own dependency.

But even without doing so, you can still directly import from a transitive dependency.

TypeScript will only complain if it cannot find it in your `node_modules`, whether you have listed it as a dependency or not.

You can also use TypeScript utility types: `ReturnType<typeof createAxiosClient>`
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype

Obviously, if possible, you would have your custom dependency re-export whatever is exposed by its API.

Comment: The `ReturnType<typeof createAxiosClient>` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!